# Regular Expression match and extraction

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, awk

I am writing a shell script where in I need some help in matching and extracting pattern

```
ALARM_TYPE contain string 'Exception Type - timeOverThreshold Description - High CPU eHealth Alarm ID - 1000001'
```

I need to extract the string after `Description -` and before `Alarm ID` and store it in a new varaible ...speciafically in this example I am looking for `High CPU eHealth`

How can I do it simply does `awk`, `sed` works or any other simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a literal translation of what you want to do using `GNU grep`:

```
var=$(grep -oP "(?<=Description - ).*(?= Alarm ID)" file)
```

Or with `sed`:

```
var=$(sed 's/.*Description - \(.*\) Alarm ID.*/\1/' file)
```

Test:

```
echo "$var"
```

Results:

```
High CPU eHealth
```

---

You can read more about lookahead and lookbehind assersions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). HTH.

Comment: Thanks Steve but instead of file the string is orignally stored in a variable $ALARM_TYPE, does below snippet looks good
var=$(echo "$ALARM_TITLE" | sed 's/.*Description - \(.*\) Alarm ID.*/\1/'")

Comment: any idea how should i handle this ...
nstead of file the string is orignally stored in a variable $ALARM_TYPE, does below snippet looks good var=$(echo "$ALARM_TITLE" | sed 's/.*Description - (.*) Alarm ID.*/\1/'")

Comment: @Nik: Try this: `var=$(echo "$alarm_title" | sed 's/.*Description - \(.*\) Alarm ID.*/\1/')` OR use a here-string if your shell allows: `var=$(sed 's/.*Description - \(.*\) Alarm ID.*/\1/' <<< "$alarm_title")`

Comment: @Nik - what is the name of the variable the text is stored in? You said ALARM_TYPE but then used ALARM_TITLE in your example here and then opened a whole new question using yet a 3rd variable. Also - copy/paste what steve is telling you, don't try to re-type it as it looks like you are messing that up..

Comment: Thanks for reply Ed, Steve.
i tried this 
var=$(echo "$alarm_title" | sed 's/.*Description - \(.*\) Alarm ID.*/\1/')
but it is passing the whole string alarm_title in var, so output of var is $alarm_title and not just High CPU

Comment: @Nik: I cannot reproduce your error. The only difference between your command and mine is that you're not escaping the parenthesis inside of `sed`. This however, should generate an error message like: `invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`. Can you `echo` a test string into `sed`? Does that work?

Comment: Actually that is not a difference Steve, this is when i am pasting the command here it is showing the missing escape charachter otherwise i used what you have said

Comment: you mean echoing a test into sed?

Comment: Is there a alternate option can i use awk or grep ...shall we try this

Comment: @Nik: I would find the fact that the above `sed` command not working for you quite concerning. I would continue testing. Perhaps there's extra whitespace that's messing you around? The equivalent `awk` command is: `var=$(echo "$alarm_title" | awk '{ gsub(/.*Description - | Alarm ID.*/,"") }1')`. Goodluck.

Comment: Steve, if i can ask why do we have | after Description - , what does this signify

Comment: @Nik: `|` simply means `OR`. So, substitute `.*Description - ` to nothing and substitute `Alarm ID.*` to nothing. I could have written: `awk '{ sub(/.*Description - /,""); sub(/ Alarm ID.*/,"") }1'` but I'm getting lazy. Got it working?

Comment: still not. i am seriously missing something.

Comment: try changing every space in your substitution regexp to [[:space:]]+ in case you have tabs or multiple spaces in your string, e.g. `Description[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]+...`

Comment: @Nik: I really can't say what's going on. But if I were you, I would start with some more basic testing. For example, can you get your `sed` to delete the word `Description` from your input sting? Does sed's capture grouping and substitution work? I.e. can you use `sed` to capture the word `Description` and add content beside it?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*Description\(.*\)Alarm.*$/\1/g'
```